# VBA 438 error - Object doesn't support this property

Tags: excel, vba

I have a public Excel file(and set as read only), and everything works well on my work machine(machine A).

But when I tried to execute the VBA program via ActiveX button on another machine (machine B), Excel pop out 438 error. And when tried to check the VBA program on machine B, it shows nothing in the window (but the code does exists if I check it via machine A).

Could anyone tell me what happened on machine B?
Last Thurs. the VBA program can still works on machine B, but it just failed when I executed it today.
Would any MS patch impacts this?

Comment: I've had problems recently where files have started saving as xlsx rather than xlsm, thus stripping out the code. This seems related to a recent update. Is it possible that the user on B has saved the file and it's removed the code?

Comment: Users on B has no right to modify read-only file, they can only key in data and then click ActiveX button to pass data to Access database.
And it's weird that I can see the code on A machine. I'll try to roll back patch or rename the extension name.

Comment: Just found that after re-install MS Access Database Engine can solve situations like application or .xlsm Excel throw out exception of operation through ADO connection...still not sure which MS patch will cause these symptoms.